# How to solve python error while installing npm package?

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I was getting following error when trying to install any npm package. Sharing the solution for the same in answer.

```
F:\workspaces\myProject>npm install sphere-node-product-csv-sync --global
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\product-csv-sync -> C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sphere-node-product-csv-sync\bin\product-csv-sync

> dtrace-provider@0.8.8 install C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sphere-node-product-csv-sync\node_modules\dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js


C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sphere-node-product-csv-sync\node_modules\dtrace-provider>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sphere-node-product-csv-sync\node_modules\dtrace-provider
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
+ sphere-node-product-csv-sync@4.1.0
added 318 packages from 230 contributors in 88.082s
```

Answer (score 1):

This got solved after rebuilding npm.

`npm rebuild node-sass`